# Electron | onbeforeunload prevents reloading

Tags: electron

I'm trying to develop an app with a separate settings window (in electron). When the settings window is open and the main window is closed, I want to prevent the closing of the main window and focus the settings window.

Right now I do this as following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = e => {
    console.log(e);
    if(settingsWindow) {
        settingsWindow.focus();
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    else e.returnValue = true;
};
```

This although prevents reloading the window, which I don't want.
So I'm asking for a different preventing method or a way to detect if it is a reload or a close.

Greeting Elias =)

**EDIT/Solution:**
utilize `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` to handle everything with creating windows in the main process. There you can catch and prevent the `close` event.

**MAIN.JS**

```
const {ipcMain} = require("electron");
...
ipcMain.addListener("ASYNC_MSG", (event, arg) => {
    switch(arg) {
        case "OPEN_SETTINGS": createSettingsWindow(); break;
    }
});

...

mainWindow.addListener("close", e => {
    if(settingsWindow) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        settingsWindow.focus();
    }
    else e.returnValue = true;

});
```

**RENDERER.JS**

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
...
ipcRenderer.send("ASYNC_MSG", "OPEN_SETTINGS");
```

Comment: what about [`'close'` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-close)? It's called _before_ `onbeforeunload` and doesn't collide with reloading

Comment: Mhh yeah but I could not get that to work... I found out a solution to the problem though. =)

Comment: added implementation for 'close' event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`'close'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-close) event, which is called *before* `onbeforeunload` and doesn't collide with reloading

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let main = new BrowserWindow({title: 'main'})
  let settings = new BrowserWindow({title: 'settings'})

  main.on('close', (event) => {
    if (settings) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.returnValue = false
      settings.focus()
    } else {
      event.returnValue = true
    }
  })
  settings.on('closed', () => {
    settings = null
  })
})
```

Comment: Is this a better way to do it? If so I gladly implement it (check out my answer)

Comment: Well, if you want to tackle the reload problem, too, yes. Otherwise it's just matter of style. But destroying something in a "destroy-is-ongoing" callback doesn't feel proper to me (I couldn't tell you exact side effects though)

Answer (score 0):

Soo after some more trial and error I found out that this works:

```
window.onbeforeunload = e => {
    console.log(e);
    if(settingsWindow) {
        settingsWindow.focus();
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    - else e.returnValue = true;
    + else window.destroy();
};
```

Glad I finally found a solution :)

Comment: Is it possible to call this in a (I think it's called so ^^) renderer process, because I don't initialise my settingsWindow in the main process and remote.getCurrentWindow().addListener("close", ...) doesn't seem to work :(.

Comment: How do u initialize the settings window then? `window.open`?

Comment: No actually `settingsWindow = new remote.BrowserWindow({...})`

Comment: Then u can simply `ipcRenderer.send` an event to Main process and initialize it there to make things coherent